# How to force dismiss video playing in full screen from webview?

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, webview

I am playing video in UIWebView using html.

```
NSString *Str = @"<video controls> <source src=\"video_1.mp4\"> </video>";
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video_1" ofType:@"mp4"];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:Str baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
```

User can enter in full screen while playing video.

But I want to exit from full screen mode to normal mode.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: exit while playing or do you want to disable full screen mode?

Comment: are you using any player to play the video?

Comment: exit while playing... i just loading video in webview using html.